# FreeText Annotation Appearance Stream In Landscape PDF Using iText

Tags: annotations, itext

This is my code to create appearance stream for a free text annotation.

```
cs.rectangle(bbox.getLeft() , bbox.getBottom(), bbox.getWidth(), bbox.getHeight());
cs.fill();

String[] text = new String[1];
text[0] = "BAC"

cs.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), pdfJSAnnotation.getFontSize());                        
cs.beginText();
cs.setLeading(fontSize + 1.75f);
cs.moveText(0, bbox.getHeight() - fontSize + .75f);

for (String s : text) {
    if (s.equals("\n")) 
        cs.newlineText();
    else 
        cs.showText(s);
}

cs.endText();
```

where cs is PdfAppearance, bbox is Rectangle. This works okay when pdf is portrait. however, im having problems when it is in landscape, say if page rotation is 270.

The text shown is vertical. and even if i use cs.transform() to rotate, it does not even rotate properly. I also tried to save the state, do a rotate then display text and then call cs.restoreState() after cs.endText() but the outcome is still not correct.

any ideas?

the rectangle is correct since the 1st 2 lines where it fills a rectangle shape is correctly displayed. it is the text i am having problems with.

Comment: For clarification: **A** Are you in a document creation situation (`Document` & `PdfWriter`) or a document manipulation situation (`PdfReader` & `PdfStamper`)? **B** Do you use `cs` as `PdfContentByte` argument of `PdfAnnotation.createFreeText` or do you use it in a later `PdfAnnotation.setAppearance` call? **C** Do you set the `PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_NOROTATE` flag?

Comment: hi mkl. A) PdfWriter, B) setAPpearance c) did not set no rotate. Took me a day but i managed to put up the correct translate and rotation values to position the free text in the right orientation (270 degrees).

Comment: Also, i thought that when I did appearance.saveState(), all drawn there can be rotated. but it seemed that only the area to be drawn is rotated, not the content. which was why i resorted to finding the right translate and rotation values for 270 degree landscape page.

Comment: Do you already have resolved the issue?

Comment: @mkl yes. this is resolved

Comment: In that case please either answer your question yourself or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is:
 - set appearance dimension to (height,width) since it is 270 degrees.

Then in the PdfAppearance object:

- translate it to (height, 0);
- rotate to 270
- translate to (-height,-height);

(Tried to remove this post but there is no option available)